# Update query just showing zero values when there exists non-zero values. (ACCESS)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have been struggling with this for hours. I am trying to update all values that have the same '**SHORT#**'. If the '**SHORT#**' is in **017_PolWpart2** I want this to be the value that updates the corresponding '**SHORT#**' in **017_WithdrawalsYTD_changelater**. This update query is just displaying zeroes, but these values are in fact non-zero.

So say **017_WithdrawalsYTD_changelater** looks like this:

```
SHORT# WithdrawalsYTD
1          0
2          0
3          0
4          0
5          0
```

and  **017_PolWpart2** looks like this:

```
SHORT# Sum_MTD_AGG
3          50
5          12
```

I want this:

```
SHORT# WithdrawalsYTD
1          0
2          0
3          50
4          0
5          12
```

But I get this:

```
SHORT# WithdrawalsYTD
1          0
2          0
3          0
4          0
5          0
```

I have attached the SQL for the Query below.

Thanks!

```
UPDATE 017_WithdrawalsYTD_changelater 
INNER JOIN 017b_PolWpart2 ON [017_WithdrawalsYTD_changelater].[SHORT#] = 
                 [017b_PolWpart2].[SHORT#] 
SET [017_WithdrawalsYTD_changelater].WithdrawalsYTD = [017b_PolWpart2].[Sum_MTD_AGG];
```

**EDIT:**
As I must aggregate on the fly, I have tried to do so. Still getting all kinds off errors. Note the table **17a_PolicyWithdrawalMatch** is of the form:

```
SHORT# MTG_AGG     WithdrawalPeriod       PolDurY
1          3                 1            1
1          5                 1            0
2          2                 1            1
2          22                1             1
```

So I aggregate:

```
SHORT# MTG_AGG     
1          3                 
2          24
```

And put these aggregated values in  **017_WithdrawalsYTD_changelater**.

I tried to this like so:

```
SELECT [017a_PolicyWithdrawalMatch].[SHORT#], Sum([017a_PolicyWithdrawalMatch].MTD_AGG) AS Sum_MTD_AGG
WHERE ((([017a_PolicyWithdrawalMatch].WithdrawalPeriod)=[017a_PolicyWithdrawalMatch].[PolDurY]))
GROUP BY [017a_PolicyWithdrawalMatch].[SHORT#]
UPDATE 017_WithdrawalsYTD_changelater INNER JOIN 017a_PolicyWithdrawalMatch ON [017_WithdrawalsYTD_changelater].[SHORT#] = [017a_PolicyWithdrawalMatch].[SHORT#] SET 017_WithdrawalsYTD_changelater.WithdrawalsYTD =Sum_MTD_AGG;
```

I am getting no luck... I get told SELECT statement is using a reserved word... :(

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: I have edited... hope this is clearer. Thanks!

Comment: The query looks right to me at first glance. Are you actually executing the query? or just looking at the "results" by clicking the datasheet view button?

Comment: Ah...may well be that I cannot run the query - I get the error 'action or event blocked by disabled mode', but just appears in bottom left corner. I go onto database tools and even still I don't see the route to turning this off? (I have tried following guide online but it doesn't work as there is no ' Show/Hide' in database tools tab....

Comment: Is `017_PolWpart2` an aggregate (GROUP BY) query? Cannot run UPDATE if an aggregate query is involved. Although normally the error message is 'must be an updatable query'. Should not save aggregate data, just calculate when needed. Just build SELECT query that joins the aggregate data to source data. - you already have that JOIN in the example SQL.

Comment: @June7 Ah, yes it is. This is really out of my depth I am not natural in sql, so I have been struggling to do your suggestion. I will change my original answer to display my edit...

Comment: Why are you struggling? Should be simple with query designer. Nothing really unusual about these queries.

Comment: @june7, I don't see how you can run both an update query and sum whilst grouping in SQL

Comment: Exactly what I said - CANNOT run an UPDATE query when an aggregate is involved. Just build a SELECT query. Nothing unusual about SELECT query joining tables and/or queries. Get rid of the UPDATE. And use LEFT or RIGHT JOIN, not INNER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider heeding @June7's comments to avoid the use of saving aggregate data in a table as it redundantly uses storage resources since such data can be easily queried in real time. Plus, such aggregate values immediately become historical figures since it is saved inside a static table.

In MS Access, update queries must be sourced from updateable objects of which aggregate queries are not, being [read-only](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html) types. Hence, they cannot be used in `UPDATE` statements.

However, if you really, really, really need to store aggregate data, consider using [domain functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Expressions-684295d0-97c2-443c-8e0a-8c6b635bec56#ID0EAABAAA=Domain) such as `DSUM` inside the `UPDATE`. Below assumes *SHORT#* is a string column.

```
UPDATE [017_WithdrawalsYTD_changelater] c
SET c.WithdrawalsYTD = DSUM("MTD_AGG", "[017a_PolicyWithdrawalMatch]", 
                            "[SHORT#] = '" & c.[SHORT#] & "' AND WithdrawalPeriod = [PolDurY]")
```

Nonetheless, the aggregate value can be queried and refreshed to current values as needed. Also, notice the use of table aliases to reduce length of long table names:

```
SELECT m.[SHORT#], SUM(m.MTD_AGG) AS Sum_MTD_AGG
FROM [017a_PolicyWithdrawalMatch] m
WHERE m.WithdrawalPeriod = m.[PolDurY]
GROUP BY m.[SHORT#]
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Happy coding, GladMrSmile!